# continuous integral function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $K$ be a countinuous and bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable on.

a) show that $$g(t)  = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} K(tx)f(x)dx$$
is conituous and well defined.

b) suppose that all partial derivatives of $K$ exists and are bounded, and that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\max|x_j| |f(x)|dx < \infty$$
show that g is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

For the well-definedness note that
$$g(t) < \sup |K|  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)| dx < \infty$$
I guess I can use dominated convergence for the continuity, but what about part b?
can I use some mean value theory for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both a) and b) can be solved by dominated convergence.

For a), we only need to show sequential continuity. Fix $t\in \mathbb R$ and $(t_n)_n$ a sequence converging to $t$. Then define $$F_n(x):= K(t_nx)f(x).$$

For b), fix $t\in \mathbb R$ and $(h_n)_n$ a sequence converging to $0$. Then define 
$$F_n(x):=\left|\frac{K((t+h_n)x)-K(xt)}{h_n}-xK'(xt)\right|f(x).$$